# Pushing object into array erases instead of adding

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a function like this :

```
$scope.saveSearch = function () {
    var alreadyExist = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedSearch.length; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify($scope.searched) === JSON.stringify($scope.savedSearch[i])) {
            alreadyExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!alreadyExist) {
        $scope.savedSearch.push($scope.searched);
        localStorage.setItem("savedSearch", JSON.stringify($scope.savedSearch));
    }
};
```

Before that  : `$scope.savedSearch = [];`

```
$scope.searched = {
    IS: "",
    area: "",
    block: "",
    type: "",
    level: ""
};
```

The values in `$scope.searched` object are initialized and then modified by the user.

My problem is :
`$scope.savedSearch` always contains **only** the last pushed object. Instead of adding the object to the array, it just replaces the current object.

I don't understand why.

Comment: Why do you `JSON.stringify($scope.searched)`? Isn't `$scope.searched` a string?

Comment: You don't show us how/where you *read* `$scope.savedSearch`, you just tell is that it is `[]` before the code you run. As far as we can tell, it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do.

Comment: @Cerbrus : `$scope.searched` is an object.

@meagar : I'm not sure I understood what you meant, I initialize `$scope.savedSearch` as an empty array, and I want my function to add the current `$scope.searched` object into this array.

Comment: much better ways to compare... you aren't accounting for angular hashkeys added to objects as well as you always push the same object reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to change your push line to:

```
$scope.savedSearch.push(angular.copy($scope.searched));
```

I believe your problem is that objects are passed by reference.  Since the object you have in the savedSearch is always pointing to the exact object you're searching, alreadyExist will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the object *reference* is being stored in your array, not the actual object itself. Because of this, any subsequent calls to push the object to your array will not work because the object reference already exists in the array. It's merely updated.

Try this instead. Use `angular.copy()` to create a deep copy of the object and push the copy to your array. See if that works.

```
if (!alreadyExist) {
  $scope.savedSearch.push(angular.copy($scope.searched));
  localStorage.setItem("savedSearch", JSON.stringify($scope.savedSearch));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, resolved went to the first to post, you're getting an upvote though.

Answer (score -1):

You are pushing the Object outside of the for so only 1 element get pushed in try move it inside the for and every object which doesnt already exist will be pushed in

```
$scope.saveSearch = function () {
var alreadyExist = false;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedSearch.length; i++) {
    if (JSON.stringify($scope.searched) === JSON.stringify($scope.savedSearch[i])) {
        alreadyExist = true;
        break;
    }

if (!alreadyExist) {
    $scope.savedSearch.push($scope.searched);
    localStorage.setItem("savedSearch", JSON.stringify($scope.savedSearch));
  }
 }
};
```

easier way would be to just

```
$scope.saveSearch = function () {
var alreadyExist = false;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.savedSearch.length; i++) {
   if (JSON.stringify($scope.searched) != JSON.stringify($scope.savedSearch[i])) {
       $scope.savedSearch.push($scope.searched);
       localStorage.setItem("savedSearch", JSON.stringify($scope.savedSearch));
   }else{
     break
   }
 }
};
```

Comment: I think the point in that function is to push only 1 object. The loop is there to check if the object already exists (so it doesn't post duplicates)

Comment: well thats why there is the if statement so every object which is not already in there is getting pushed in

Comment: The for is there only to check the existence of `$scope.searched` in `$scope.savedSearch` array.
Doing like you suggested would just push n times `$scope.searched` from what I see

Comment: why when it is pushed once it is always a duplicate!? After the first time it wont be pushed in since its duplicated right?